# Tag Wiki vs Community Wiki vs Self-Answered Questions

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki, self-answer, community-wiki

I've just recently posted this: [How do I use annotations to define different types of relationships in Hibernate 4 and Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257449/how-do-i-use-annotations-to-define-x-relationship-in-hibernate-4-and-spring) to basically give myself a SO resource that I can use when answering people's questions about setting up Hibernate relationships using annotations because as I say in the comments, I'm sick of typing out the same object structure again and again when giving examples. I also see so many people

I was planning to do some other questions in a similar vein on things like transaction management best practices, how to create an effective DAO/Service layer in Spring with declarative transactions and how to deal with lazily loaded collections.

I realise that they would be helpful in the tag wiki, but

1. I don't have the rep to edit tag wiki's without everything being reviewed and;
2. I want to continue improving these over time.
3. What new user ever reads the tag wiki?

I considered making my first one a Community Wiki. However, my intention is to provide a single resource for people to use rather than 25 answers from every TDH<sup>1</sup> with a keyboard that people have to trawl through to find what is actually helpful.

Should I make these questions community wiki and just watch the answers closely or should I leave them as a self-answered Q&A style question? I was a little disheartened that I got a near instant VTC for "Not a Question", but I live in hope.

<sub><sup>1</sup>Tom, Dick and Harry</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That close vote probably came from the giant wall of bold-italic text that takes up 1/2 of the question yet has nothing to do with the question. And the fact that the question isn't actually a question, it is a blog post. **You need to ask the question in question format**. You didn't do that here.

Please don't take this the wrong way, but my suggestion is to spend less time wringing your hands about the system and just *use it*. We allow self-answered questions for a reason. If you have knowledge to share, Q&A style, [you're encouraged to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). See also: [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Creating canonical questions with high-quality answers is a well-accepted practice and something you are to be commended for taking the time to do. You *can* make these community wiki if you want, but don't feel any pressure to do so. As long as the answer is *mostly* yours, you deserve the credit for creating it. Writing good canonical questions and answers is *hard*.

Aside from that, [the standard rules about Community Wiki posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) still apply. See also: [Putting the Community back in Wiki](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki/)

And there's nothing wrong with people who have something different to contribute posting *new*, *separate* answers, just like any other question. Obviously you don't want a proliferation of useless, wrong, or duplicate answers. But you don't ever want that on any question. The community already has tools to handle that situation, including protecting a question and downvoting/deleting these answers.

As far as the tag wiki goes, I'm not sure where the community stands on that. I remember a long while ago (back before the Meta SO/Meta SE split), there were suggestions that all kinds of canonical information be located in the tag wiki, but I think that died out after people realized the limitations of the tag wikis: primarily that they are not easily discoverable, that questions cannot be closed as duplicates of a tag wiki, they quickly get lengthy and unwieldy, etc. Various proposals to make tag wikis "richer" and more wiki-like have mostly fallen by the wayside. I take that as a sign that the community now feels it would be more appropriate to put this information into questions and answers. If you want to edit the tag wiki to *link* to the canonical questions, that would of course be appropriate. (You don't need 20k reputation to suggest edits to the tag wiki.)

Comment: Updated my question to try and rephrase the question part as an actual question, and removed the bold italics to a subscript disclaimer. I'll continue to improve it. Thanks for your help

Comment: The disclaimers seem like they belong in the *answer* to me. The answer is the thing that provides the examples you are disclaiming, not the question. The question should be something like "How can I…blah blah blah?"

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to point these things out