# How to use Stack Overflow Community Wiki

Tags: support, community-wiki

I am new to the Stack Overflow and trying to learn about using Community Wiki.

Comment: Perhaps [Tag Wiki vs. Community Wiki vs. Self-Answered Questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260748/62576) might help.

Comment: IIRC, new users cannot make a community wiki post because they tend to misuse it. You need a certain amount of rep to do so.

Comment: Got it very useful information Mysticial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might help clear some things up for you: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/

The community wiki is just a way to open up your answer for editing/approval by experienced users, but you should probably try to avoid using it:

"Most of the time, you should be asking yourself “How can I improve this post so that community wiki isn’t needed?” Community wiki is like a cheese knife: it is a specialized tool to be used sparingly."

Comment: Exactly but I dont see that option showing up.

Comment: The checkbox will only show up now when posting answers, not questions.

Comment: I am doing the exact same thing and it makes complete sense to make Community Answers and not questions as Q's are already available out there.

Comment: This isn't quite correct. CW has nothing to do with editing/approval. It's for posting answers that belong to the community, which means that no one gains or loses any reputation for votes it receives. It's commonly used when posting an answer based on something someone else provided in a comment, for instance; you give credit to the comment and it's poster, post the info as an answer, and mark it CW so that you don't gain from using someone else's answer. The post you linked is almost 4 years old, and use has changed quite a bit since then.

Comment: Hi Ken, was your reply for Giene or for Mir?

Comment: Both I should think.

Comment: Kewl, got it...

Comment: @Giene It was intended to reply to this answer, which is why I posted it here under the answer. :-)

Comment: Mir, [here's an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30078832/62576) of the use I described, written recently. Note the accept checkmark and the upvotes? I gained nothing in the way of reputation from any of them because I made the answer CW.

Comment: Got it. I'll admit, I'm still learning about this site myself. Thanks.

Comment: I am not able to add attachments but Mir, I just tried to answer to the question which you have sent just now. Still dont see it.

Comment: May I know who and why was this migrated?

Comment: @Giene: Stack Overflow is for questions about programming. Your question is not about programming; it is about the Stack Overflow site itself. Questions about Stack Overflow go on this site, Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks Greg, just learned about that few mins ago. I just created this account infact.

Comment: @Giene: There is no site here that allows you to upload attachments, community wiki or otherwise. When you have earned sufficient privileges, you can include images inline in your posts. ([Privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) are explained in the [help] under the *Reputation and Moderation* section. You probably should spend some time reading through the [help], as it contains a lot of useful information that will make your experience here much better.)

Comment: Thanks Ken, Yes I am doing the same right now. I appreciate all your proactive responses.

Comment: @Giene: One more *proactive response*. :-) When you want to address a comment to a specific user (either the asker of a question, an answerer, or someone in a previous comment), use the at sign (as I've done here to address you). It directs the comment into that person's inbox so they're aware of it.